# jQuery iterative Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, iteration

I want to create a **jQuery** iterative **timer**. For this I wrote the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t;
    function x()
    {
        alert('x')
        t = setTimeout("x()",1000);
    }
    x();
});
```

First time the function ***x()*** called successfully. But from the next function ***x()*** is detect as ***undefined***. What could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you define x() in closure. Define x as global function. Or pass it as function, instead of string:

```
function x() {

};

setTimeout(x, 1000);
```

Comment: What about `arguments.callee`?

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);            
});


function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    $('#box span.start:not(:empty)').each(
        function(s) {
            var start = $('#box').children('span.start').html();
             $('box').children('span.time').html(formatMillis(now.getTime() - start));
        }
    );
    window.setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Don't use a string in `setTimeout`

   ```
   setTimeout(x, 1000);
   ```

   or

   ```
   setTimeout(function(){ x(); }, 1000);
   ```
2. `SetInterval` is your friend in these situations

   ```
   setInterval(x, 1000);
   ```

Note that the function you pass to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` will be passed lateness (the number of milliseconds late the timer actually fired) as the first argument. This won't affect you just yet (since `x` doesn't take any arguments), but may bite you later on. This won't be the case if you use an anonymous function (second example), since it'll receive the lateness argument.

Answer (score 0):

function x() is only visible inside the anonymous function. Try putting function x() outside the callback for the onload event. That is,

```
function x()
{
  alert('x')
  t = setTimeout("x()",1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var t;
    x();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the jQuery [Timers plugin](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/)

Answer (score 0):

Read your latest comments and I tried to integrate Jorge's `updatetime()` (html object id) box  combo (Oct 8 at 19:22). It is clean, I like it. In my integration, `updatetime()` get called every second but the code inside function(s) never gets executed.

Could it be because my html object is not valid? It is in the body and defined as `<div id="box"><p>time</p></div>`.

Stephane

P.S.: My version of Jorge's updatetime function is

```
function updateTime() 
{
        var now = new Date();
        $('#box span.start:not(:empty)').each(
                function(s) 
  {
                        var start = $('#box').children('span.start').html();
                         $('box').children('span.time').html(formatMillis(now.getTime() - start));
                }
        );
        window.setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using `setInterval` instead?

[W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_setInterval.asp)